# Azure "Only empty App Service plans can be deleted" error

Tags: azure

I'm tried to delete an Azure App Service plan, but Azure threw a fit:

> The App Service plan has 1 apps. Only empty App Service plans can be deleted.

No problem - I need to remove the Web app from the App Service plan.

I thought that navigating to the App Service plan's `General > Apps` page would do it, but that page just gives you a *read-only* list of the Web apps installed in the App Service plan.

I'd like to move this Web app to another App Service plan, or delete it altogether.  How do I get past the `Only empty App Service plans can be deleted` error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Navigate to the App Service you want to move to a new plan.
2. On the management blade, look under the App Service Plan heading. There's a menu option of "Change App Service Plan".
3. Select the new plan you'd like to move the App Service to.

Comment: Thanks Rob - this wasn't easy to find.  It took a minute or two for Azure to register that I moved the app - I still got the error a couple times even after the app was moved to a new App Service plan.

Comment: @alex Agreed, it should be on the Overview page just like you can change the Resource Group and Subscription.